# Why doesn't Cognito fetch/show the Google/Email attribute with Sign in with Google?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using the Amplify/Authenticator component and setting up a Social sign-in (OAuth) with Google.

The scheme with email/password works fine, but the one with Google seems to fail - Cognito shows that after signup with Google, the Email field is empty and Email-verified is false (No).

What am I missing in the process? It looks that the sign-up with Google is not completed.
I do get some attributes captured from Google (e.g. pictures).

[Cognito settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okGzj.jpg)
[Attributes captured from Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OivKo.png)

```
export default function AuthPage() {
  return (
    <Authenticator
      initialState="signIn"
      components={components}
      formFields={formFields}
      socialProviders={["google"]}
    >
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.attributes.nickname}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

Here is the outcome with an email/password signup.
I was expecting to get the same with Google.
[Email sign up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUKX2.png)

Authenticator does not perfrom as expected as it does not block signing up with same emails (Sign UP w/ Google and Sign Up w/ Email).